# 403 Forbidden error when installing software in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: kubuntu, software-installation

When I try to install software in Kubuntu 14.04 it shows these errors:

```
http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qca2-plugin-gnupg/libqca2-plugin-gnupg_2.0.0~beta3-2_amd64.deb
403 Forbidden
http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kdeconnect/kdeconnect_0.5.2.1-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
403  Forbidden`
```

Comment: *What* are you trying to install and *how*?

Comment: i just installed kubuntu 14.04 then i used muon discover to install vlc

Comment: before that i used Update the System, from within Konsole:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade

Comment: This seems to be a misconfiguration of the Bangladeshi update server. Try another one (for example replacing *bd* with *fr* in URLs works fine).

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: replacing bd with fr in URLs

Comment: please help me!

Comment: As @fkraiem points out, this is a bug in the mirror. It has been reported to the mirrors admins.

Comment: This bug should now be fixed, you can continue to use the Bangladeshi mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open 'Software and Updates' from Unity dash. On the first tab 'Ubuntu Software' of 'Software and Update' window select 'Server for United states'. The authentication window will pop up. Put your password and click 'Authenticate'.

After you put your password press close on 'Software and Update' window. It will ask for refresh. Do that.

AK